# How spring cloud sleuth works?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

How spring cloud sleuth works behind the scenes?. Will it be able to trace library calls also?. Im having a spring boot project A which uses  library B. Any hit to endpoints in project A is traced by sleuth, but when I try to hit rest controller on Library B sleuth fails to trace the request. Is there a way to tell sleuth to trace library calls also?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spring Cloud Sleuth up till version 2.0 has its own tracer and since 2.0 it's reusing https://github.com/openzipkin/brave . A tracer is responsible for passing of the tracing context. What does it mean? It means that you have to propagate the tracing information:

- what is the current span (span is a unit of work)
- what is the current trace (trace is an id for all unit of works forming a single business operation)

Having the tracing information propagated in-process (between different libraries, threads etc.), and out of process (via Http headers, messaging etc.), Sleuth is able to process this information and store it locally in order to continue the trace.

You need to use the `SpanInjector` and `SpanExtractor` (prior to Sleuth 2.0) or Brave's handler mechanisms to properly handle receiving and sending of spans.

Comment: Thank you Marcin !!

Comment: Hi, @Marcin-Grzejszczak, is there any way to see what values being set in headers and when they are being set, can we print those details in the log?

Comment: You can turn in debug logging then you might see which span is set for the given instrumentation. However the best way would be up use Wireshark or sth like that to check the packages and headers or just print it out in the recipient side

Comment: Thanks, @Marcin-Grzejszczak. Do we have any in-built classes in slueth to print the headers? will Tracing Filter help in this case?

Comment: We don't have anything pre-built

Comment: @Marcin-Grzejszczak.if I have to do it, which classes of slueth i can use and how i can do it?

Comment: Create a normal filter that runs after the tracing filter and just print out headers